# ros-pcl libraries don't work on my cpu?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have the following error everytime i use something related to the PCL:
**illegal instruction (core dumped)**

E.g. i execute *voxel_grid table_scene_lms400.pcd test.pcd*, or *pcd_viewer table_scene_lms400.pcd*, and i get the error "illegal instruction".

gdb output (for voxel_grid):

```
0x00007ffff740b769 in pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::applyFilter(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&) () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_filters.so.1.5
```

gdb output (for pcd_viewer):

```
0x00007ffff74886a5 in pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRandom<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::getColor(vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray>&) const () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.5
```

I installed ubuntu 12.04 and ros on a new hard drive, but if i plug the drive into another PC, the error don't occure.

My CPU is: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz (flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority)

My system: 64bit ubuntu 12.04

Is it possible, that some flags are used for the precompiled ros-binaries, which doesn't work with my cpu?

cheers
Robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44038/ros-pcl-libraries-don%27t-work-on-my-cpu?/) by [robert_81](https://answers.ros.org/users/3151/robert_81/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robert_81](https://answers.ros.org/users/3151/robert_81/) on 2012-09-18**:
Hi again, perhaps i was not clear with my description: I used here both binaries of the deb-packages (voxel_grid and pcd_viewer), it doesn't work on one PC, but when i take the hard-disk and put it into another PC (with another cpu), it works!? i think the binaries are not compatible with my CPU?

**Comment by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on 2012-11-21**:
I'm having the same issue, code that runs fine on one machine crashes with illegal instruction on another (in this case an Intel i7 vs AMD Phenom II). Voxel grid does again seem to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue comes from your use of sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 inside the voxelgrid. It appears to only take a [point.](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_voxel_grid.html) Try just a pcl::PointXYZ and run it.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on 2012-11-21**:
The example on the PCL site uses sensor_msgs::PointCloud2! I have voxel grid code that runs ok on one machine with either type (PointXYZ, PointXYZRGB, PointCloud2) but throws Illegal Instruction on another machine with either type.